# Счетчик рисунков в LaTeX

Tags: latex

Скажите, пожалуйста, есть такой? У Львовского говорится про `figure`, но этот счетчик относится к плавающим рисункам.

Answer (score 0):

Да, счетчики для таблиц и рисунков связаны с плавающими объектами (окружениями). Кроме этого, окружения для обтекания рисунков текстом тоже связаны с тем же счетчиком. Если еще точнее, то с этими окружениями связаны команды для подписей, а уже они используют счетчики. Таким образом, если Вы будете использовать с рисунком подпись, то получите и номер рисунка. А используя команду `captionof` (из пакета `caption`) Вы можете использовать подпись *вне* указанных окружений и, соответственно, использовать счетчик для рисунков.

Comment: Vladimir, вы не поняли меня. Вот я вставил простой рисунок, не плавающий, не обтекаемый. Существует ли счетчик, значение которого при этом изменилось?

Comment: Не понимаю, что такое; добавляю @ к обращению - оно вообще исчезает.

Comment: @mathem, насколько мне известно, у команды вставляющей рисунки нет своего счетчика. Что Вы хотите от счетчика? Хотите отдельный счетчик от счетчика плавающих рисунков?

Comment: @mathem, когда Вы пишете комментарий к моему ответу - уведомление мне присылают автоматически, указывать имя через '@' при этом не нужно. Вот если захотите обратиться к другому человеку (не к автору вопроса или ответа), тогда для посылки уведомления нужно использовать '@'.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно создать отдельный счётчик для таких рисунков.

```
\newcounter{illustration} %или другое имя на своё усмотрение
```

Потом его можно крутить вручную или автоматически через `\newcommand` и `\renewcommand`

---

PS
Раз Вы читали Львовского, то подробно расписывать не буду - у него написано лучше про это.

Comment: А для тех, кто не читал Львовского? Для них ваш ответ будет скорее всего безполезен.  Возьмите на заметку, на этом ресурсе принято отвечать на вопрос ТС, а не самому ТС лично, чтобы другие также могли воспользоваться решением.

Comment: Спасибо за замечания, учту. Я сначала хотел дописать свой вариант кода, но мне желательно бы увидеть код спрашивающего - неясно, какой способ он использовал, а, следовательно, может быть там есть свой счётчик и новый заводить смысла нет.

Comment: Спрашивающий не заходил с 6 марта. Будете ждать?

Comment: @0xdb Надеялся, что придёт по уведомлению о новом ответе.